# Help Required with validation rule formula

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I want to show validation error if the selected lookup record type is not special. Below is the formula I am using.

```
ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In') && car__r.RecordType.Id <> '012q00000000V2R'
```

I have also tried creating recort type id formula field and record type name formula field and than compare with the value but that didn't help.Code for both of tham is as follows.

```
ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In') && car__r.RecordTypeId <> '012q00000000V2R'
```

and

```
ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In') && car__r.RecordTypeName <> 'Special'
```

None of the above code works as it does not give any error while I select type as In and select car from lookup of type Special.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In') && car__r.recordtypeId <> '012q00000000V2R'`

it will give error only if Picklist field Type is IN and recordType != Special.
But if you want only `RecordType` validation then you only use

```
car__r.recordtypeId <> '012q00000000V2R'`
```

or if you want to use both then you can use

OR(`ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In') ,(car__r.recordtypeId <> '012q00000000V2R'`))

`ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In') || car__r.recordtypeId <> '012q00000000V2R'`

Also i suggest you never direct reference Id. just store this into hierarchical Custom setting and then refer the custom setting. it will give you more control also if you move your field into another org or create a managed package then it will help you to update the value
**Note** Also check that Validation rule is active.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts @Tushar.

I want to through error only when Type__C is in and record type is Special. That is why i have used && also I need to know If I use record type name instead of id will that be identical in all orgs?

Comment: yes it is. Did it works for you i also share code with and condition.

Comment: Hey Both of them are for or ? I don't see AND

Comment: check the first one. the first line

Comment: Ohh I see that now so you mean to say I can straight use car__c instead of car__r ?

Comment: I have tried using that and it says car__c field does not exist

Comment: in the validation rule you can bind field direct using field selector. Just select your field using it.

Comment: This is what i was doing and it returns car__r.recordtypeId .

Comment: my bad . Update my answer.Did it works for you

Comment: After edit its exactly same formula what I was using, And that doen't work

Comment: @Ricky = This comment "f I use record type name instead of id will that be identical in all org" Needs addressed. The ID Will NOT be the same in all orgs, only the DeveloperName will be. Just wanted to ensure you were aware that IDs are **almost** never the same across orgs

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you it might be happening that the Id's you are comparing are 15 and 18 digit Id's.
A possible solution would be comparing 'DeveloperName' of record type instead of Id's.
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You complete requirement is not clear from your question.

but from one of your comments *"I want to through error only when **Type__C is in** and **record type is Special**."*

then you should check both for equals.. but you are checking not equals for record type in your formula... change it to below and it should work

```
AND(
   ISPICKVAL(Type__c ,'In'),
   car__r.RecordTypeName = 'Special'
)
```